# How to close if case in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My SQL statement is like this

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Bid_Create]

    @BidNo nchar(12)
    ,@BidType int
    ,@ClientId int
    ,@BidDate date
    ,@EmailNotificationStatus int
    ,@BidStatus int,
    @BidAmount int

AS

DECLARE @highestBid int;
BEGIN
    Begin Try
      Begin Transaction

        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        set @highestBid = (SELECT Max(wf_bid.BidAmount) as HighestBitAmount from  wf_bid where wf_bid.ProductId = '1')
        IF @highestBid=@BidAmount
             UPDATE wf_bid SET BidType=@BidType ,ClientID=@ClientId ,BidDate=@BidDate , EmailNotificationStatus=@EmailNotificationStatus,BidStatus=@BidStatus 
             WHERE Id= ( SELECT TOP 1 id
             FROM [wf_bid]
             WHERE BidAmount = (Select Max(BidAmount) FROM [wf_bid] WHERE ProductId=101 and ClientId=101))
                INSERT INTO wf_bid
                    (BidType,ClientId,BidDate,EmailNotificationStatus,BidStatus)


                VALUES
                    (@BidType,@ClientId,@BidDate ,@EmailNotificationStatus ,@BidStatus)
       Commit Transaction
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        Rollback Transaction
    End Catch

END
```

My problem is that If case gets closed after first `update` statement itself. I want it to close after only second Insert statement also gets executed. What change I need to make in the query to make this possible?

Comment: Use `BEGIN` and `END`

Comment: you should include your ELSE part within a BEGIN END pair (BEGIN in the line before update, END; after your insert)

Comment: @LovepreetSingh that's about MySQL, not SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the complete use should be:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Bid_Create]

@BidNo nchar(12)
,@BidType int
,@ClientId int
,@BidDate date
,@EmailNotificationStatus int
,@BidStatus int,
@BidAmount int

AS 

DECLARE @highestBid int;
BEGIN
Begin Try
  Begin Transaction

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    set @highestBid = (SELECT Max(wf_bid.BidAmount) as HighestBitAmount from  wf_bid where wf_bid.ProductId = '1')
    IF @highestBid=@BidAmount
    BEGIN
         UPDATE wf_bid SET BidType=@BidType ,ClientID=@ClientId ,BidDate=@BidDate , EmailNotificationStatus=@EmailNotificationStatus,BidStatus=@BidStatus 
         WHERE Id= ( SELECT TOP 1 id
         FROM [wf_bid]
         WHERE BidAmount = (Select Max(BidAmount) FROM [wf_bid] WHERE ProductId=101 and ClientId=101))
            INSERT INTO wf_bid
                (BidType,ClientId,BidDate,EmailNotificationStatus,BidStatus)


            VALUES
                (@BidType,@ClientId,@BidDate ,@EmailNotificationStatus ,@BidStatus)
   END
   Commit Transaction
End Try
Begin Catch
    Rollback Transaction
End Catch

END
```